# How to SSH to target AWS machine using a bastion host

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, aws-security-group

Assuming `Machine A` is target machine which I want to SSH into finally while `Machine B` is a bridge machine (bastion host). These two machines are accessible using the same PEM file.

The security group of `Machine A` allows SSH connections only from `Machine B`. So If I want to connect to `Machine A`, I need to connect through `Machine B`.

How can this be accomplished without placing the `PEM file` on the bastion host?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ProxyCommand](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-ssh-proxycommand-passing-through-one-host-gateway-server/). I prefer defining the following in your `~/.ssh/config` file.

```
host MachineB
 HostName <MachineB-IP>
 IdentityFile <Full Path of .pem file>
 User username

host MachineA
 HostName <MachineA-IP>
 ProxyCommand  ssh MachineB nc -w 120 %h %p
 IdentityFile <Full Path of .pem file>
 User username
```

Then access MachineA like:

```
$ ssh MachineA
```

Answer (score 1):

To reach an EC2 instance in a private subnet via a bastion host in a public subnet, without placing your SSH private key on the bastion, you need to use SSH agent forwarding.

Specific instructions are provided [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/securely-connect-to-linux-instances-running-in-a-private-amazon-vpc/).